# SQL Alchemy automapped model and MapperEvents - how to add hybrid properties on automapped model?

Tags: sqlalchemy

SQL Alchemy `2.0.22`

I have a model derived from `automap_base`

I want to programmatically add some hybrid properties to the automapped model. (The hybrid properties need to reference Column attrs which only exist after the automap has been 'prepared').

I am following the suggestion in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096082/202168

So I created an event handler like:

```py
AutoMapped = automap_base()

class MyModel(AutoMapped):
    ...

@event.listens_for(MyModel, 'mapper_configured')
def add_hashed_pseudo_columns(mapper, model):
    print("mapper_configured")
    ...
```

But I seem to have a chicken and egg problem...

If I register the handler before the `prepare` call:

```py
@event.listens_for(MyModel, 'mapper_configured')
def add_hashed_pseudo_columns(mapper, model):
    print("mapper_configured")
    ...

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
AutoMapped.prepare(autoload_with=engine)
```

I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedClassError: Class project.MyModel is a
subclass of AutomapBase.  Mappings are not produced until the
.prepare() method is called on the class hierarchy.
```

If I register after `prepare` call then the handler is never called and my properties don't get added.

Is there a way to achieve this?